# Xpath expression with multiple predicates

Tags: xml, xpath, predicate

I am trying to build a complex xpath expression which will answer the following condition.

From the XML data below, returns the **User** entity which:

1. His loginname is "**user1**"
2. His name is "**User 1**"
3. He has 2 different profiles values which are "**operator**" and "**admin**" (I don't know the exact order ahead)

   ```
   <user>
     <login>user1</login>
     <name>User 1</name>
     <profile>
       <value>admin</value>
       <id>2</id>
       <description>admin users</description>
     </profile>
     <profile>
       <value>operator</value>  
       <id>1</id>
       <description>Operator</description>
     </profile>
   </user>

   <user>
     <login>user2</login>
     <name>User 2</name>
     <profile>
       <value>admin</value>
       <id>4</id>
       <description>admins users</description>
     </profile>
     <profile>
       <value>poweruser</value>  
       <id>5</id>
       <description>power users</description>
     </profile>
   </user>

   </root>
   ```

Can someone please supply an example for such a case?

**EDIT: Added a complex profile entity**

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The following should do what you're after:

```
/root/user[login='user1' and 
           name='User 1' and 
           profile='admin' and
           profile='operator']
```

Having two tests for the `profile` value might seem odd, but as there are multiple `profile` nodes then the condition will be satisfied as long as at least one node matches the test.

The reason you can compare `profile` directly to a `string`, even though it actually is a `node` is that the `string-value` of an element node is the `string-value` of all its descendants concatenated together, which in this case is just the contents of `value`.

If `profile` contained more elements than `value` you'd have to use a slightly more complex predicate test to determine the existence of a matching `profile` node based just on the `value` (this should work with your updated question):

```
/root/user[login='user1' and 
           name='User 1' and 
           profile[value='admin'] and
           profile[value='operator']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution. 
May I use an XPATH like this one, or it may change the logic:
/root/user[login='user1' ][  name='User 1' ][ profile[value='admin'] ][profile[value='operator']]

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know you could have multiple predicate blocks, but yes, it looks like that works too. Cool, now I have learned something as well :-)

Comment: Multiple predicates only function as AND of course, the expanded syntax gives you OR too, but I prefer multiples for clarity. You could also do this with axes like preceding-sibling but that would be a bit obtuse for a simple case like this.

Comment: @Greg Beech: But you could check for duplicates this way, for example "//user[name = preceding-sibling::user/name]". Predicates can be as deeply nested as you wish.

Comment: The first expression seems outdated (probably the OP changed the XML after the initial solution was posted, by adding the "value" elements). The second expression is OK, but it does not check that the "user" element has *exactly* two "profile" children.

Comment: @Dimitre - The question didn't ask for exactly two profile elements (or I didn't read it as such) but a simple "and count(profile)=2" could be added if that was required.

Answer (score 8):

**Here is a more exact answer** (at present Greg Beech's answer does not check for condition 3. in the problem: the `user` element must have exactly 2 `profile` children):

```
/*/user
        [login='user1' 
        and            
         name='User 1' 
        and  
         not(profile[3])
        and          
         profile/value='admin' 
        and           
         profile/value='operator'
         ]
```

Comment: Thanks for showing possibility how to check exact number of elements.  That said, I still don't read condition 3 as "must have exactly 2 and (not 3 or more)".

Comment: @AloisMahdal, The question states: "3.He has 2 different profiles values which are "operator" and "admin"".  The XPath expression in this answer checks exactly this -- he has the profiles of 'admin' and of 'operator' and he hasn't a third profile. If there was a third profile value, the user would actually have 3 different profile values -- not 2.

Comment: A job description says that I need to speak French and German.  If I speak French, German and Italian, do I qualify?  This is about English:  I'm not a native speaker and not a linguist so I might be wrong, but way I read it, I assume that unless explicitly said (say, if they really need that you must not speak Italian), such lists are never exclusive.  (Note that I'm not intended to prove you wrong, I was just pointing out a "grey zone" in the language.  Sorry for semi-OT)

Comment: @AloisMahdal, I completely agree that natural language has its ambiguities. This is why in many cases we are trying to guess the real meaning of a questions. Not always our guesses are correct and we only know for sure, if the OP has clarified -- which isn't the case with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `users` is the root:

```
/users/user[login='user1' and name='User 1' 
            and (profile='admin' and profile='operator')]
```

Comment: I believe you mean "login" etc (not "@login" etc). These are elements, not attributes in the orginal XML. ;-)

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking :P

Answer (score 0):

```
/root/user[login='user1' and name='User 1' and profile/value='admin' and profile/value='operator'
```