# xpath query for finding an element with a condition which matches the attribute and child node value

Tags: xml, xpath, selectsinglenode

I have 2 elements with same attribute but with different child node values. Can I query to find a specific element which matches the attribute and also the child node value. To be specific, this is the sample xml i am using to query(each element in original xml has more than 10 childe nodes).

```
 <Book size="2">
  <Title>abc</Title>
  <Price>10</Price>
 </Book>
 <Book size="2">
  <Title>xyz</Title>
  <Price>20</Price>
 </Book>
 <Book size="4">
  <Title>Harry</Title>
  <Price>10</Price>
 </Book>
```

So, now I want to find the Book element which has the `@size = "2"` and `Title = xyz`.

Is this possible by using `SelectSingleNode` method? If not how to query this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xpath expression with multiple predicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568713/xpath-expression-with-multiple-predicates)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This:

```
//Book[@size='2'][Title='xyz']
```

Or this:

```
//Book[@size='2' and Title='xyz']
```

Note that the use of `//` is discouraged when your schema is known.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
//Book[@size='2']//Title[text() = "xyz"]/..
```