# Combining Predicates In XPaths

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, predicate, google-search-appliance

I have some XML like this:

```
<MT N="tag1" V="text"/>
<MT N="tag2" V="more text"/>
<MT N="tag3" V="other text"/>
<MT N="tag4" V="something cool"/>
<MT N="target_tag" V="i want this"/>
<MT N="target_tag" V="and this"/>
```

I'm trying to target the `MT` where `N=target_tag` and by number (1 or 2).

The following doesn't work, despite what I was hoping from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568713/xpath-expression-with-multiple-predicates):

```
<xsl:variable name="display" select="MT[@N = 'target_tag' and 2]/@V" />
```

If I try this, I consistently get the first one:

```
<xsl:variable name="display" select="MT[@N = 'target_tag']/@V" />
```

And if I try this, I consistently get the second MT tag (so "more text" in this example):

```
<xsl:variable name="display" select="MT[2]/@V" />
```

I've tried this with no luck too:

```
<xsl:variable name="display" select="MT[2][@N = 'target_tag']/@V" />
```

Based on my requirements, I need to combine them, so that when I'm looping through a recursive function I can show the first, then the second, then the third.

Any ideas how these can be combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select="MT[@N = 'target_tag'][2]"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Input XML:**

```
<root>
<MT N="tag1" V="text"/>
<MT N="tag2" V="more text"/>
<MT N="tag3" V="other text"/>
<MT N="tag4" V="something cool"/>
<MT N="target_tag" V="i want this"/>
<MT N="target_tag" V="and this"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="MT">
            <xsl:if test="@N = 'target_tag'">
                <xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

*i want thisand this*