# Xpath expression with both an ID and contains Text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

So I have the following tag I want to find using Xpath:

```
 <h1 id="label">This is the text</h1>
```

Normally, I would write it like this:

```
//h1[@id='Label' and text() = "This is the text"]
```

Or, if I want to extract just partion of the text, I use the following:

```
//h1[text()[contains(.,'text')]]
```

Now, I tried to look for tutorials wether you can mix both statements: so I want to have an Xpath Expression that contains both @id and contains the text "Text".
Is such a thing even possible?

I tried doing this:

```
//h1[@id='Label' and [contains(@text,"text"])]
```

But that doesn't give me a propper result.

Comment: I often use "contains", but there are more. Here are some examples:

    multiple condition: //h1[@id='Label' and contains(text(), 'text')]
    partial match: //span[contains(text(), 'Assign Rate')]
    starts-with: //input[starts-with(@id,'reportcombo');
    value has spaces: //div[./div/div[normalize-space(.)='More Actions...']]

    sibling: //td[.='LoadType']/following-sibling::td[1]/select"

    more complex: //td[contains(normalize-space(@class), 'actualcell sajcell-row-lines saj-special x-grid-row-collapsed')]

Comment: @Andersson If you dup hammer questions based on the above granularity level, each question is duplicate of some existing at least with `selenium` tag. Can we reopen this question?

Comment: @DebanjanB , This question does not benefit the community: if it's not a duplicate, then it should be closed as "Simple typographical error": note that OP uses closing parenthesis/square brackets incorrectly. If that typo fixed then... OP just should check [how to use multiple predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568713/xpath-expression-with-multiple-predicates)

Comment: @Andersson For the time being let us keep apart the advanced topic of _multiple predicates_ theory. OP is a new user. Our efforts should be to provide the new users a effective experiance. As you correctly pointed out `Simple typographical error`, that where new users expect help. Perhaps dup hammer was harsh here.

Comment: @DebanjanB , actually, first help is the traceback of syntax error that OP got and Andrei Suvorkov has already provided with correct answer. OK, if you have something to add - reopened

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace:

```
//h1[@id='Label' and [contains(@text,"text"])]
```

with:

```
//h1[@id='label' and contains(text(),'text')]
```

Comment: Note that OPs' XPath is syntactically incorrect and you just copied one of the errors: replace `@text` with `text()`